# How apply different media queries rules for a specific div?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on AB Testing variation for a website that use tons of CSS rules and I'm wondering if there is a possibility to apply their classical 767px view media queries for a unique div (something like an iframe behavior)

Indeed, we try to add a second div to give more information and we reduced the size of the original div that used to live with **width:100%**

I would like to do something like this :

```
<main>
<section>
  <div class="Original_Div">   //Apply CSS like browser is 767px
  </div>
  <div class="New_Div">   //Apply normal CSS
  </div>
</section>

</main>
```

Perhaps this will help better understanding

[Actual Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cdKs.png)
[Variation variation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kXmo.png)

Massive thanks !!

Comment: I'm confused. So for tablet you want to use `Original_Div` and for normal you want to use `New_Div`

Comment: @JamesS it's difficult to explain ahah 
No, I would like to make my div act LIKE if it is on a browser width of 780px or 760px or whatever, like an iframe behavior but just for a unique div

Comment: I'd encourage you to have a go at it! One way that comes to mind is to copy the relevant media query block, but instead of a media query, make it dependent on a class which you then apply to the div.

Comment: @tobiv Is there a way to select Media Queries that only corresponds to 600px-767px devices as there are 15k lines of CSS ^^

Comment: Copy the original media query, put it in after the original and override anything that needs to be overridden. Copy `original-mq { .original-css { ... } }` and insert after `copy-from-original-mq { .original-css { override } .additional-css { ... } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add any extra styling you like by adding more style blocks to your html. The example below has a media query that will give you the red div only at screen widths of up to 768px. For sizes bigger than that (e.g. a laptop or desktop) then the green div appears. To ensure the div gets no larger than 768px (e.g. a typical tablet size) then use the max-width css rule. If you want to control the height also to make it look like it's a tablet screen then you can use the aspect-ratio css rule (see [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/) for info)

If you're modifying someone else's html then make sure you use a unique class name or id so you control your specific elements. The inspector on the browser's web developer tools (on firefox it's Ctrl + Shift + I) is useful to find out what's actually being rendered.

```css
body {
  background-color: #282C34;
}
 section {
  display:flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  height:80vh;
 }

 section > div {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
 }
 .Original_Div {
  flex-grow:1;
  max-width:767px;
  border: 0.25rem solid red;
  color:red;
 }

 .New_Div {
  flex-grow:1;
  border: 0.25rem solid #00ff00; 
  color: #00ff00;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .New_Div {
    display:none;
  }
 }
```

```html
  <main>
    <section>
      <div class="Original_Div">
        Original with media queries that fit this width
      </div>
      <div class="New_Div">
        New block
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help !
My aim is to only make this Variation accessible on desktop, I do not care of screen that are smaller dans 1100px.
But I would like to apply CSS rules of Media queries normally applied to 600px-767px on the Original Div. Something like this Div would be an iframe of 6xx or 7xx px
The rest of the page act like normal

Comment: Okay. Looks like container queries may be the way to go. It's fairly new to css and I think it's still in the development stage. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you have asked. You want to behave a div in tablet media query while at the same time the other div should behave on media queries of normal Document size.

You can apply tablet media queries to a specific div and add !important so it will override other media queries that may have applied to its parent div/body element.

You can do the same for other div where you want to apply regular media queries.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .Original_Div {
    max-width: 80% !important;
    display: inline !important;
  }
  .New_Div{
  max-width: 20% !important;
    display: inline !important;
  }
}
```

If I misunderstood your requirements, do let me know so I can provide you with right solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help !
What I would like is to write no new CSS line but instead apply CSS that correspond to screen between 600px and 767px 
Perhaps is there a way to filter the global css to get only those rules and remove Media Queries mention to force the application of it